# Make Div enter a search value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, forms

I would like to make this div tag "tile 1" to be selectable and upon clicking it retrieves search results based on a key word.

```
<div id="tile1" class="live-tile" data-swap="image" data-direction="horizontal" data-stops="80px,90%,100%,90%,0" data-delay="6000">       
<div>
<img class="full" src="../bakeware2.png" alt="2" />
</div>
<div>
<img class="full" src="../bakeware3.png" alt="3" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the code that I use for my search bar.

```
<table align="center">
   <tr>
     <td align="center"><form action='search.asp' method='post'>
       <div style="float:left;">
         <input type="search" style="color:#000;"  name="keyword" size="30" data-mini="true" value="bakeware">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        <input type=image src="http://www.kitchenova.com/assets/templates/v32029/images/btn-search.gif" border="0" />
        </form></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can make the div "tile1" click-able and have it display the results as if I were to type in say "cookies" in the actual search bar itself?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for jQuery, attaching a click event to an element should be documented extremely well!

Answer (score 1):

Is this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tbrv/) what you're looking for?

JS

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
       var typeaword = $('#getme').val();
       typeaword = '123' + typeaword + 'xyz';
       $('.putmehere').html(typeaword);
});
```

Comment: close, but I would like it to actually run the search.